# Not able to plot categorical data properly using matplotlib library in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, data-analysis

Here were my 3 assigned data analysis tasks:

- Display the complaint type and city together.
- Plot a bar graph of count vs. complaint types.
- Display the major complaint types and their count.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

work_on = data[['Complaint Type','City']]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
%matplotlib inline

koten = work_on['Complaint Type'].value_counts().head(10).plot(kind='bar')
koten
```

-- [bar graph that was obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36ban.jpg)
-- Which displays a bar graph but when i use the following code:

```
style.use('ggplot')
plt.plot(work_on['Complaint Type'].value_counts().head(10))
plt.xlabel('Values')
plt.ylabel('Names')
plt.title('first')
plt.show()
```

-- this throws an error:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Traffic Signal Condition'

My question being: I am using the .plot(kind=) method which only works for kind='bar' which displayed the graph that i shared but when i use the matplotlib method it started giving me errors such as: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Traffic Signal Condition'. Is there any other good method in python to display such non-numerical data?

Here is a glimpse of my data:
[Two columns to be worked on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7QFf.jpg)

Comment: `plt.plot` plots numerical data. Your data is not numerical. What are you expecting the resulting plot to look like?

Comment: If i have 10 types of unique names in my data say A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J i want to display A - 10 times in the data, B - 20 times in the data... In short the frequency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from the question what the desired plot should acutally show. If it is a line plot accross the different categories, you would need to provide the indizes of the categories to the `plt.plot` function.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([])
df["ComplaintType"] = np.random.choice(list("ABCDEFGHIJ"), size=50)

counts = df["ComplaintType"].value_counts()
plt.plot(range(len(counts)), counts)
plt.xticks(range(len(counts)), counts.index)
plt.show()
```

[image]

It is a bit questionable in how far it makes sense to connect different categories by a line though.

Comment: What does the plt.xticks(range(len(counts)), counts.index) do here?

Comment: Leave it out and you see the difference. It names the ticks on the xaxis to read your category names.

Comment: Can you give a look into the bar graph i shared? This is the type of graph which is required. Since you said "plt.plot plots numerical data" what method can i use to display the data i shared?

Comment: Now I'm lost. If you already have a code that produces the graph you want (which is a bar graph) what is the purpose of the question?

Comment: The question is: I am using the .plot(kind=) method which only works for kind='bar' which displayed the graph that i shared but when i use the matplotlib method it started giving me errors such as: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Traffic Signal Condition' . Is there any other good method in python to display such data?

Comment: There are some 20+ plotting methods in matplotlib. I think the aim should be to imagine a type of graph you want to have and then find a way to obtain that graph. Using the pandas `.plot(kind="bar")` is a good choice. If you don't want a bar graph, you can tell which kind of graph you want and I can give you the solution.